# install ipython for current python version 2.x

Tags: python, ipython

The python version is 2.7.6 but when I install IPython

```
sudo pip install ipython
```

ipython it points to python 3.4.0.  This leads to many syntax errors in modules that I commonly use due to python 3.x incompatibility.

I try editing the first line of the script /usr/local/bin/ipython:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
```

becomes

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

But then I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named IPython
```

How can I get Ipython and my default python version (2.7.6) to work together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ipython2` to start a ipython2 shell, if you need to install for python2   use `pip2 install ipython`. `pip` obviously points to python3 on your system so specifying `pip2` will install ipython for python2.

Whatever the  shebang points to will mean typing just `ipython` will start a shell for that version of python so if you had `#!/usr/bin/python3.4` then `ipython` will start an ipython3 shell and vice-versa.   Unless you have Ipython actually installed for python2 then changing the shebang won't do anything but error.

Comment: So when I install something via pip does it always apply to only one version of python?!

Comment: @Selah, yes exactly,  packages are not necessarily compatible with both versions of python, python3 is not backwards compatible with python2 so you could not install a universal package for both

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to install Ipython for lower version of python you should check the compatibility.

If you simply try to install Ipython with the below command, there is a chance you end up installing the latest version of Ipython. Which has the compatibility issue which varies version to version.

```
$ pip install Ipython
```

Best solution would be to find the compatible version of Ipython from the below link.
[Ipython release history](https://pypi.org/project/ipython/#history)

For example Python 2.X supports Ipython below 5.X. It will be good to install

```
$ pip install ipython==4.2.1
```